# how to configure zend to access netezza

Tags: php, zend-framework, netezza

I am looking for help configuring Zend Frameworks to work with Netezza.  I am new to zend but looking at the docs, appears I need to specify a resources.db.adapter and not sure what to use.

Should I use ODBC to connect?  guessing I need to find that driver from Netezza.

What else will I need?

Jay

Comment: I  did find the Netezza client/drivers on FixCentral and for my version it was: Fix pack: 7.2.0.3-IM-Netezza-NPS-fp87194

Comment: Everything I have read makes me believe I will need to create a Netezza db adapter...

Answer (score 0):

I am using ODBC driver for Netezza with PHP with no issues. You will need to get/install the Netezza client on the OS your are on. Add the ODBC software for the OS. Once you have done this add the DSN. Test the connection at this level it will save you alot of time. Once you have got this talking to Netezza DB can be done with php_odbc or pdo_odbc I have just tested both with Netezza and they work with no issues.